# Sagemaker AWSWrangler>2.3.0

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-data-wrangler

As I am trying to use the function read_excel as part of AWS Wrangler, available as of version 2.3.0 in Sagemaker Jupyter Lab on Amazon Web Services, it does not install properly. The Python version of the Conda Instance is 3.6.

When running !pip install awswrangler >=2.3.0 directly in the notebook, the error provided is

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory:
> '/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3transfer-0.5.0.dist-info/METADATA'

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, only version 2.14.0 is available via pip. Did you try updating pip?
Reference: https://pypi.org/project/awswrangler/